# Trying to change value of my submit input on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a list of posts in my page, and I also have a form to search for posts.

This is my form:

```
<form  action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search"   onclick="if(this.value=='Search:')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search:'" value="Search:" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" class="search"  name="sendForm" />
</form>
```

And then, when my form is submited with some values I store a session with my sql condition statment and I get only my list of news that have title like the value I wrote in my input.

And then, If I submit my form without any value I unset my session and I get my list of all news again.

This is my php:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendForm'])){
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    if(!empty($search) && $search != 'Search:'){
    $_SESSION['where'] = "WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'";
    }
    else{
        unset($_SESSION['where']);
        header('Location: dashboard.php?exe=posts/index');
    }
 }
```

And now I need to change value of my input sumbit when I submit my form.

At first, my submit value is "Search", and when I click in it I want to change this value to "Clear".
 And when I click in "Clear" I want to change to "Search" again.

Do you know how can I do this correctly?

I tried like this at first, but didnt work fine:

```
<input type="submit" value="Search"  onclick="if(this.value=='Search:')this.value='Clear"  name="sendForm" />
```

And now Im trying using toogle, but also its not working correctly.

```
$(".search").toggle(function (){
           $(this).val("Search");
        }, function(){
        $(this).val("Clear");
});
```

Comment: Check your jquery version, `toggle` you are using is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Shaunak, I put my class  in wrong place on my question, now I update it correctly. But I still have the same problem, Im changing the value to "Clear" but as Im refreshing my page, my value backs again to "Clear"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y5AU6/)

1. `toggle() - click` is deprecated - **[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)**, current `toggle()` by jQuery hides the element.
2. Use `preventDefault()` for preventing form submit, if you need.

Check this code,

```
var clear = true;
$('.search').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();          //if required
    if(clear){
        $(this).val('Clear');
        clear = false;
    }
    else{
        clear = true;
        $(this).val('Search'); 
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks Shaunak D, your code works perfectly. But I think I need to do this with php, because when I click on my submit I send a request to the server and page is loaded, and so the value changes to "Clear" but then immediately switches back to "search". But your answer is correct, but do you know some way to do this server-side?

Comment: Yes, that is why I said, preventDefault should be optional if the submit required server side coding.

Comment: Thanks! But even with preventDefault it is not working as it should. At first I have "Search" then I write some text and click on "Search", and my value change for one second to "Clear" and then after my refresh I have again "Search", and I just want again search when I click again on my submit!

Answer (score 0):

If your form is in a php file you can set a php variable (eg, $submitValue="Search"), then plug that value into your form code:

```
<input type="submit" value="<?= $submitValue ?>" class="search"  name="sendForm" />
```

You're trying to change the value of the submit button, right?